# How to integrate Select2 plugin on JQuery datatable CellEdit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

In my application, I have already integrated a JQuery datatable. However, I want to add an inline editor. Jquery datatable has a facility for inline editing, but this is not free.

So, I searched another inline editor on Google and found an open source lib [CellEdit](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit) which provides inline editing. I have successfully implemented it in my datatable and it is working well.

However, I want to add the [Select2 JQuery plugin](https://select2.org/) into the drop down, because my application datatable drop down contains a number of values. So, I'm unable to select values easily. The Select2 plugin provides a search option, in the drop down, which I use to can find the exact option easily. However, [CellEdit](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit) does not have that facility. Can anyone help me to add Select2 plugin?

**Current Drop Down**

[image: Drop down screen shot]

**Desired Drop Down (with search option)**

[image: Drop down with search option screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

I tried suggestion from @jawahar N and did not see the expected output. I realized that i had not defined the "myselect" css class.

If you want a quick output, use class "js-example-basic-single" instead of "myselect". This is recommended in select2.org website https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage.

And dont forget to add select2 css class and javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and couldn't able to find any solution. So, I studied this ( https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit ) core JS files.

That is available in this path ( https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/tree/master/js ).

And finally, I found a solution to this issue.

In the **Core JS file**, they handled all input types( textbox, drop down, date field ) on **'getInputHtml' function**.

Actually, In this plugin, they wrote code for 2 types of drop down. One is with confirm and cancel button, This is called **'list-confirm'** and another one is, **'list'** without any buttons. It's automatically handled by onChange.

So, In this **'getInputHtml' function** they wrote a switch case for both two types of drop downs.

1. case "list-confirm"
2. case "list"

**To integrate select2 plugin we need to do the following things,**

1. Need to add a class name in our drop down like `select class="myselect"`
2. Need to add this below code inside of script,
   `$(".myselect").select2();`

If you need drop down with search option. Please replace my below code instead of old code in the core JS file,

**1. case "list-confirm":**

```
case "list-confirm": // List w/ confirm
    input.html = startWrapperHtml + "<select class='myselect " + inputCss + "'>";
    $.each(inputSetting.options, function (index, option) {
        if (oldValue == option.value) {
            input.html = input.html + "<option value='" + option.value + "' selected>" + option.display + "</option>"
        } else {
            input.html = input.html + "<option value='" + option.value + "' >" + option.display + "</option>"
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".myselect").select2();
    },100);
    input.html = input.html + "</select>&nbsp;<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='" + confirmCss + "' onclick='$(this).updateEditableCell(this);'>Confirm</a> <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='" + cancelCss + "' onclick='$(this).cancelEditableCell(this)'>Cancel</a>" + endWrapperHtml;
    input.focus = false;
    break;
```

**2. case "list":**

```
case "list":
        input.html = startWrapperHtml + "<select class='myselect" + inputCss + "' onchange='$(this).updateEditableCell(this);'>";
        $.each(inputSetting.options, function (index, option) {

            if (oldValue == option.value) {
                input.html = input.html + "<option value='" + option.value + "' selected>" + option.display + "</option>"
            } else {
                input.html = input.html + "<option value='" + option.value + "' >" + option.display + "</option>"
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".myselect").select2();
        },100);
        input.html = input.html + "</select>" + endWrapperHtml;
        input.focus = false;
        break;
```

Now, We can able to view the search option inside of the drop down. please see the below screen,

[image]